# apply function to any element of the columns in loop for each column

Tags: function, loops, apply, median

I have a df named bb:

```
A B C D
0.5 5 2.3 1.7
1.7 2.1 4.5 2.5
3.2 4 8.5 7.9
```

for each column calculate median.
and then apply this function to each element of the df:

```
median([abs(x-y)])
```

where x is each element of the column and y is the median value obtained in the upper step (in the order).

and this is what I did:

```
mad = []
for col in bb.iteritems():
     for x in col[1:]:
            for y in medianx:
                zz = (median([abs(x-y)]))
                mad.append(zz)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
medianx= []
for column in qq:
    print(column)
    medianx.append((median(qq[column].values)))

cc = qq.columns.values.tolist()

# create a list of column names
columns_list = cc

# create a list of median values
for column in qq:
    print(median(qq[column].values))
median_list = medianx

# calculate MAD for each value of the column
mad_list = []
from scipy.stats import median_abs_deviation
for i,col in enumerate(columns_list):
    mad_col = qq[col].apply(lambda x: median_abs_deviation(x))
    mad_list.append(mad_col)
mad_list1 = mad_list[mad_list > 1.5]
```